# Submit a form in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-hook-form library to be able to work with forms. This is my custom created form:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const Form = ({onSubmit, children}) => {
  const {handleSubmit, formState: { errors }} = useForm();
console.log(errors, 'errrerrr')
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>{children}</form>
  )
}

const Input = ({fProps, ...rest}) => {
  const { register } = useForm();

  return <input { ...rest } {...register('name',fProps) } />
}

export default function App() {
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data, 'details');
  
  return (
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
     <Input name='name' type="text" placeholder="First name" fProps={{required: 'please add data', min: 1}}/>
     <input type="submit" />
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Clicking on submit button i expect inside `console.log(errors, 'errrerrr')` the error, because user does not added a value, but i don't get any values. How to fix that and to get the error?

 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-glade-385kqc?file=/src/App.js